# Visual Studio Code PHP Intelephense not hilight probably unset variables

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, unset, intelephense

[image: Example code]

Visual Studio Code PHP Intelephense not hilight probably unset varuables.
How enable hilight probably unset varuables? PhpStorm do it.
Code:

```
        foreach ($paymentCollection as $payment)
        {
            if (!$payment->isInner() && !$payment->getPaySystem()->isCash())
            {
                $summ =  $payment->getSum();
            }
        }

        if ($summ > 0)
```

$summ not hilighted ($summ = float|array $summ)

Comment: Seems like the best place to report this OR ask the question would be to the intelephense developers [Here](https://community.devsense.com/t/issue)

Comment: Did you find solution? I'm having the same problem.